# Flip two rows of a datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

I Have a datatable in .net. I need to flip the location of two of them. For example, a datatable that the select statement had an order by priority clause. The user wants to up the priority of a single row by selecting it and clicking increase priority, how do i move a row up (AKA flip two rows)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DataView` on this table, sorted by an "priority" column. When you want to increase priority, increase this column, and decrease it on the row above. The `DataView` will reflect the change on the UI.

```
Private _view As DataView

...

_view = New DataView(theTable, "", "priority", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
dataGridView1.DataSource = _view

...


' Increase priority of row at index i
If i > 0 Then
    Dim row = _view(i)
    Dim previousRow = _view(i - 1)
    row("priority") = row("priority") + 1
    previousRow("priority") = previousRow("priority") - 1
End


...


' Decrease priority of row at index i
If i < _view.Count - 1 Then
    Dim row = _view(i)
    Dim nextRow = _view(i + 1)
    row("priority") = row("priority") - 1
    nextRow ("priority") = nextRow ("priority") + 1
End
```

When you're done changing the priorities, update the database using a DataAdapter

Comment: Except it never actually switched them in memory, I would still have had to reload the datagrid

Comment: No, the DataView notifies the grid and refreshes it automatically. You don't *need* to switch the rows in memory, you only need the *apparent* order to change...

Comment: does this also update the background datatable? I would imagine so but I just have to check

Comment: Yes, it does. Changes to the view are reflected on the table, and vice versa. The view only performs filtering and sorting. It doesn't maintain its own copy of the data, it directly accesses the data from the table

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by either:

Updating the priority for both rows in the database, and then repopulating your grid(I'm assuming your have a grid that displays your datatable). (easiest, most costly)

Or you can update the priority in the database, and programmatically update the row indeces for both rows. (a little bit harder, cheapest)

Comment: The problem is i don't want to update the database until the user hits OK

Comment: Is the grid bound? If not, then you can just update the row indeces to move them around, and just update the db when you're ready.

Comment: Yes it is bound to a datagrid